# Fixing white portion of a merged TIFF

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, merge, gdal-merge

I am trying to add a merge layer to my project. I noticed that my merged layer has a region that is way too white, I am trying to fix that white space by adjusting the interval value from 0-255 to 0-1250, but whenever I set the values, it goes back to 0 - 255.

[image]

Here's a picture of my merged map, the link for the TIFF files are in [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/zicq2sv6dqbk475/tiff.rar/file)

Basically what I want to do is see what's in that white space, by increasing the interval to 0-1250, according to the original map scale. From what it looks like to me, it appears to not have any texture in that white area, therefore I would like to confirm it, by changing the interval.

Comment: It's possible that there isn't anything there, that whatever signal exists was clipped by the maximum value in the format. You'd need to physically change the file format (to 16-bit) in order to get values that exceed 255, and even then, if the source was saturated at 255, it won't magically increase to fill the additional space.

Comment: What happens when you display the "white" tif just by itself - do you now see gray areas?  Also, what results do you get when you view its statistics?

Comment: Well, i added the tiff images to raster layers and i noticed that the area isn't exactly missing: https://imgur.com/a/GZruXNg. It happens to the values of black and white between 0 and 255